# DialogFragment creates several dialog windows instead of one

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-button, android-dialog

I have a tabbed activity which contains two bottom tabs. The FrameLayout is filled with special layout file that I have created. This two layout files are run by java classes that are extending Fragment class. This is the brief description of what I have now.

Now comes the details about a problem. The layout file contains two EditText fields which must create a DatePickerDialog when clicked. I have implemented the dialogs using the DialogFragment class, one for both text fields. Hovewer, when I click the edittexts they produce several DatePicker dialogs, instead of one, and it is not clear what is the logic behind. It may produce 2, 3 or even 4 dialog windows.

How can I fix this problem? Here is my code:

Activity

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    FragmentTabHost mFragmentTabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quick_calculation);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mFragmentTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mFragmentTabHost.setup(QuickCalculationActivity.this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

        mFragmentTabHost.addTab(mFragmentTabHost.newTabSpec("days").setIndicator("DAYS"), DaysTabView.class, null);
        mFragmentTabHost.addTab(mFragmentTabHost.newTabSpec("date").setIndicator("DATE"), DateTabView.class, null);
    }
}
```

One of the tabView classes

```
public class DaysTabView extends Fragment {

/* 
 *    some code was not included to make easir to read 
 */

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.days_tab_view, container, false);
        mFromDate = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.fromDate);

        mFromDate.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                mFromDate.setText("");
                SetDateToDefault(1);     //some method
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt("day", day1);
                args.putInt("month", month1);
                args.putInt("year", year1);
                myDatePickerDialogFragment d1 = new myDatePickerDialogFragment();
                d1.setArguments(args);
                d1.setOnDateSetListener(datePickerListener1);   //onDateSet Listener that is not included in this question
                d1.show(getFragmentManager(), "days");
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And DialogFragment class

```
public class myDatePickerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{

    int mDay, mMonth, mYear;
    OnDateSetListener onSetDate;

    public myDatePickerDialogFragment(){
    }

    @Override
    public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
        super.setArguments(args);
        mDay = args.getInt("day");
        mMonth = args.getInt("month");
        mYear = args.getInt("year");
    }

    public void setOnDateSetListener(OnDateSetListener setDate){
        onSetDate = setDate;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), onSetDate, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend changing your `onTouchListener` with `onClickListener` on your EditTexts. The reason behind is that the touch listener will be triggered each time an event occured (such as finger down, finger move, finger up etc), whereas a click listener will only get triggered once.

So in the `DaysTabView` class, change to this :

```
mFromDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClick(View v) {
            mFromDate.setText("");
            SetDateToDefault(1);     //some method
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("day", day1);
            args.putInt("month", month1);
            args.putInt("year", year1);
            myDatePickerDialogFragment d1 = new myDatePickerDialogFragment();
            d1.setArguments(args);
            d1.setOnDateSetListener(datePickerListener1);   //onDateSet Listener that is not included in this question
            d1.show(getFragmentManager(), "days");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

return true in setOnTouchListener  instead of false.

```
if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

            // Do what you want
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

It should be like:

```
   mFromDate.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
             if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

                 mFromDate.setText("");
                SetDateToDefault(1);     //some method
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt("day", day1);
                args.putInt("month", month1);
                args.putInt("year", year1);
                myDatePickerDialogFragment d1 = new myDatePickerDialogFragment();
                d1.setArguments(args);
                d1.setOnDateSetListener(datePickerListener1);   //onDateSet Listener that is not included in this question
                d1.show(getFragmentManager(), "days");
                return true;
            }
            return false;
    }

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `onTouchListener` code

```
 mFromDate.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            final int actionPeformed = ev.getAction();
            switch(actionPeformed){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{

            mFromDate.setText("");
            SetDateToDefault(1);     //some method
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("day", day1);
            args.putInt("month", month1);
            args.putInt("year", year1);
            myDatePickerDialogFragment d1 = new myDatePickerDialogFragment();
            d1.setArguments(args);
            d1.setOnDateSetListener(datePickerListener1);   //onDateSet Listener that is not included in this question
            d1.show(getFragmentManager(), "days");
           break;
   }

   return true;

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should use ClickListener instead of  TouchListener